# How to change string from variable in yml file?

Tags: azure, yaml

I have a yml file used by an Azure pipeline for configuration.

```
variables: 
    CHANGE_URL :   $(System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI)/pull/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)
```

The resulting variable CHANGE_URL is:  https://github.com/username/project-boilerplate.git/9

The values are coming from Azure's predefined system variables. I'm trying to remove the '.git' from this string. I tried

`CHANGE_URL : sed 's/...$//' <<< $(System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI)` but that did not work. I'm not sure how much control I have with yml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a script step that does that:

```
- bash: |
    value=$(sed 's/...$//' <<< $(System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI))
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CHANGE_URL]$value"
```

and then in your subsequent steps you'd have a variable `CHANGE_URL` with the value you needed